# Can't pass through second table data to foreach in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am building a college project and i cannot pass through data from a second table with primary table / class.

When i try to pass it and access it in the view i get a try to access non object error.

this is my code below.

Gym class

```
class Gym extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
 */
protected $table = 'gyms';

public $gym;

public function reviews() 
{
return $this->hasMany('Review', 'unique_gym_id'); // represents the Review class
}
```

pages controller relevant section, i pass through data from this loop to the view.

```
foreach($gymsearchs as $gymsearch)
{

    Gym::save($gymsearch);
    $gyms[] = DB::table('gyms')->where('unique_gym_id', '=', $gymsearch->unique_gym_id)->get();
    Review::review($gymsearch);
    $reviews[] = DB::table('reviews')->where('unique_gym_id', '=', $gymsearch->unique_gym_id)->get();


}

//dd($reviews); this shows the full review object contents fine
    $data = array_add($data, 'gyms', $gyms, 'reviews', $reviews);
```

view

```
@foreach(array_slice($gyms, 0, 5) as $gym)
    {{$gym->name}} // works fine and with other objects from the $gym
@endforeach



@foreach(array_slice($gyms, 0, 5) as $gym)
     {{$gym->review}} // this gives me a trying to access non object error.
@endforeach
```

both the gym model and review model have unique_gym_id as a column

i thought this review class in the gym model should have brough the review table data with the $gym?

```
public function reviews() 
{
return $this->hasMany('Review', 'place_id');
}
```

any ideas what i am missing? thanks i am a novice to laravel and php

Comment: $data = array_add($data, 'gyms', $gyms, 'reviews', $reviews); - better use 
$data = $data + ['gyms'=> $gyms, 'reviews'=>$reviews];

Comment: cool thanks, as im a novice could you tell me why :)

Comment: clearer code works better. about your question - maybe you can add a little bit more details?..

Comment: Sure thanks, btw the line you changed let me access the $reviews in the view where as the other line did not. so thank you, 

I am trying to loop through the $gyms but then bring the relevant data from the reviews table with it.


i thought having this  public function reviews() 
{
return $this->hasMany('Review', 'place_id');
}

this in my model allowed the $gyms var to pull in data from the reviews table, as i want to loop through both were they share a common unique_gym_id, your edit i can use them both or can i use them in the loop together even if the reviews function doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told it to be a hasMany-relationship, so shouldn't it be "{{$gym->reviews}}" instead? Haven't tried it, but seems pretty odd. Also this should return an array rather then a single object, so you would have to iterate over it.

EDIT:

This whole section:

```
foreach($gymsearchs as $gymsearch)
{
   Gym::save($gymsearch);
   $gyms[] = DB::table('gyms')->where('unique_gym_id', '=', $gymsearch->unique_gym_id)->get();
   Review::review($gymsearch);
   $reviews[] = DB::table('reviews')->where('unique_gym_id', '=', $gymsearch->unique_gym_id)->get();
}

//dd($reviews); this shows the full review object contents fine
$data = array_add($data, 'gyms', $gyms, 'reviews', $reviews);
```

could probably be

```
Gym::save($gymsearchs);
$gyms = Gym::where('unique_gym_id', 'in', array_map(create_function('$o', 'return $o->unique_gym_id;'), $gymsearchs))->get();
$data['gyms'] = $gyms;
```

, as you don't seem to use the $reviews. But I don't quite grasp the intend of gymsearchs and what you are trying to do with the Review::review($gymsearch) approach. Also you should look into eager loading for this case. There is a ->with($relation) function, that can eager load all your reviews. This way you can optimise the number of queries send to the database.

Comment: Thanks for this, just to be clear as i can't get it to work, i get this
Trying to get property of non-object, so its in an array, the relationship sepecfied in the model should allow this object to be accesed via below?



 @foreach(array_slice($gyms, 0, 5) as $gym)

{{$gym->reviews}}
@endforeach

if i cant get that to work right the way above with 
$data = $data + ['gyms'=> $gyms, 'reviews'=>$reviews];
lets me access the $reviews where i could not before, but if i do a foreach and then a foreach inside to loop through the $reviews i get all 5 $reviews contents for each of the outside looop?

Comment: It should be something along the lines of: \@foreach(array_slice($gyms, 0, 5) as $gym) \@foreach($gym->reviews as $review) {{$review->reviewText}} \@endforeach \@endforeach. Where reviewText is an attribute of your Review entity. As I do not have much knowledge of the laravel templating engine, I can not say for sure how to nest \@foreach statements in it but this seems to be an appropriate way. (I had to escape the [at]-sign, as SO wouldn't allow me to comment otherwise)

Comment: Cheers Rick, ill try that now

Comment: Cheers rick i was orignally doing it wrong and calling the tabled data from the controller. hence the $reviews[]
i.e calling both tables as variables and passing it to the view, not actually utilising the model except to save, i have changed that, now what i am trying to do is your approach and just call $gyms, then in the model have the relationship bring the reviews data with it etc.

Comment: is this marked as answered now? thanks rick your explanation got it to work  exactly how you said.

Comment: Hey, glad I could be of any help. Just click the tick, next to the post you want to mark as the accepted answer. Have a great weekend.